# Can't explain velocity's behavior

Tags: java, velocity

Have velocity template like

```
#foreach($item in $items)
<tr>
    <td>$item.getClass() $item.getKey()</td>
    <td>$item.summary $item.Summary $item.getSummary()</td>
</tr>
#end
```

[Velocity manual](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#properties) sais, that I can access $item fields as getters -"getSummary()".

I pass ArrayList of ReportRow items to variable "items" and want velocity to draw item summary.
ReportRow is a simple POJO class:

```
public class ReportRow {
    private String key;
    private String summary;

    public ReportRow(String key, String summary) {
        this.key = key;
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    private String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    private void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return key + " " + summary;
    }
}
```

And when Velocity renders the text, I get:

- for the first column: "class ...ReportRow MyKey" - it's o'k - $item contains my object and it's Key field is accessible;
- for the second column: "$item.summary $item.Summary $item.getSummary()" - **WHY**?

When putting items in the context all fields are not null.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the getter is `private`. For obvious security reasons, Velocity doesn't allow calling private methods from templates. Just make the methods `public` to get it working.